# Is it possible to change the CheckBox/RadioButton Drawables in an AlertDialog.Builder?

Tags: android, android-listview

If so, how can I do this?  Even subclassing it would be easier than creating a custom `Dialog` containing a `ListView`, then creating `Adapters` and `Listeners` for that.  I already have a working `CheckBox` `Drawable` that I've used throughout my application; same for a `RadioButton`.  I'd just like to change the look of the default `AlertDialog.Builder` to use those `Drawable`s.

Thanks for any help!